# Windows 10 - after reboot first character in any text field is a tilde (~)

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-10

I'm having this strange issue with my Windows 10 installation. Every time after startup, the first character that is displayed in a text field after I type is a tilde (~). It doesn't matter if it's in explorer or a web browser or any other program.

Example, when typing 'Hello':

```
~Hello
```

I then just delete all the characters and start over again. An unintentional tilde does not appear anymore until a reboot.

I've searched the web but can't find anything related to it. I know 2 people who also have this issue. One is a colleague, the other one is someone who answered on this question on Reddit. Both have not found a cure for it.

At first I thought it had something to do with us having mechanical keyboards and maybe a driver issue, but the guy from Reddit has a regular keyboard.

Any help is welcome.

**EDIT:**

- Windows 10 Pro x64 Build 10240
- I don't have a different keyboard
- Language is set to English, keyboard set to Belgian point
- It does not happen in safe mode

Comment: What Windows 10 build do you have installed?  Have you tried a different keyboard?  What language packs do you have installed?  What version of Windows 10 do you have?  Does this happen in Safe Mode?  Update your question to include the answers to these questions.

Comment: So it does not happen in Safe Mode.  If this is new behavior start booting your system without specific applications that could cause this problem.  If it is possible change the keyboard layout.  If its possible install the update to `Windows 10 Version 1511` and see if this problem is solved.

Comment: I found the issue, it's 'Razer Synapse'. Disabled the startup, rebooted and no tilde. Started the program and tilde appears. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem can apparently be caused by [Razer Synapse](http://www.razerzone.com/synapse).  Some possible workarounds include the following:

1. Install the current version.
2. Uninstall the software
3. Disable the software from automatically starting when a user logs into the system